# boost::spirit string to array by separator

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I need to parse number from string "1/20/10/3/5". Number - is positive integers, "/" is separator.

I write the next expression:

```
('"' >> +(qi::uint_ ^ "/")  >> '"')
```

It's work fine, but parser allow the next string "1//3". How I can change my expression to fail that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `^`, the [permutation parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html), which matches `"/"` and/or `qi::uint_`.

What you want is the [list parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html): `%`.

```
('"' >> qi::uint_ % "/" >> '"')
```

Comment: Oh... Yes, thank you I got it mixed up this parsers types